# Неожиданное завершение программы заполнения двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

Компилирование программы проходит успешно, после ввода данных в переменную n происходит резкое завершение работы программы. С чем это может быть связано?

```
program l3p4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$CODEPAGE UTF8}

var
   a: array of array of real;
   n,sum,i,j: integer;

begin
   randomize;

   write('Введите n: '); read(n);
   SetLength(a,n,n);

   for i:=1 to n-1 do
   begin
       for j:=1 to n-1 do
       begin
           a[i,j]:=random(100);
           write(a[i,j]:5:2,' ');
       end;
       writeln;
   end;

   readln;
end.
```

Comment: Вроде как работает: http://ideone.com/XEXosa

Comment: На вскидку ошибок не видно, кроме того что индексы массивов начинаются с 0, а не с 1 по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, нужно было изменить read(n) на readln(n). Последний оператор readln читал нажатие Enter и закрывал программу.